# New to PowerBi - wondering if what I want to vizualize is doable?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I just started using and learning PowerBI at work this week.

No clue whether this kind of stuff is askable here, please tell me if it's not!

Basically I have a few data sets with all the same structure, and I try to make a column chart with clustered columns based on clients, with in the first group of columns the current rate and the previous year's rate for a customer, and then a little further away a second group for the second customer, etc.

Visual of what I hope to achieve (excuse the poor paint performance):
[What I more or less am aiming to produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ibBz.png)

As for the data sets, there are two kinds of excel sheets in the same file:

- client specific sheets, with in columns : client name/year/week/salespoint name/rate ; and in line, the current week (for instance if the data is from last week, it'd be year 2024, week 6)
- 2023 history, which is basically the same but all clients and all weeks (1 to 52) are concatenated in there.

Before anything else, is it even possible to do such a thing?
I thought maybe it'd require like a pivot or something to have the visual understand what's happening. But I don't know much about this mechanism yet.

I've tried looking online but I couldn't find what I wanted. Probably didn't look up the correct terms or stuff like that though.
I've tried placing several layers in the fields for the visual.
I've tried to understand how pivoting the tables would help me but failed to do so.

To calculate the rates, I average the whole table for the client and average the history table filtered on the week's number and the client name. This is a measure though so it loses the client characteristic as far as I understand since it becomes a "pure" value (?).

I also tried to just create separate visualizations for each client but the result is meh.

Thanks for ANY kind of help you'd be willing to partake upon me :D (be it a solution, guidance, or straight up telling me to read and search better!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for small multiples.

There's plenty of instructions around, for example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-small-multiples

Comment: This looks EXACTLY like it! Will look it up and try it out asap :D (never would have thought to look for 'small multiples' though)
Thanks!